# Is there a good mathematical explanation for why orbital lengths in the periodic table are perfect squares doubled?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, quantum-mechanics

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}}$The periodic table of elements has row lengths $2, 8, 8, 18, 18, 32, \ldots $, i.e., perfect squares doubled. The group theoretic explanation for this that I know (forgive me if it is an oversimplification) is that the state space of the hydrogen atom is made of functions on $\R^3$, which we can decompose as functions on $\S^2$ times functions on $\R^+$. Then $\SO(3)$ acts on the functions on $\S^2$ and commutes with the action of the Hamiltonian, so we can find pure states inside irreducible representations of $\SO(3)$. The orbital lengths depend on how these representations line up by energy, which is a function on $\R^+$. It happens that the spaces with the same energy have the form $(V_0 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_4 \oplus \cdots ) \otimes W$, where $V_i$ is the irreducible representation of $\SO(3)$ of dimension $i+1$, and $W$ is a $2$-dimensional space that represents the spin. So the orbital length is the dimension of $V_0 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_4 \oplus \cdots$ is the sum of the first $k$ odd numbers, which is a perfect square, and you double it because of the spin.

So, in short, the perfect squares arise as the sums of the first $k$ odd numbers, and the invariant subspaces arrange themselves into energy levels that way because... well, here I get stuck. Factoring out the spin, which explains the doubling, can anyone suggest a more conceptual (symmetry-based?) explanation for why perfect squares arise here?

Comment: What is $...$? How many rows are in the periodic table? The last two rows have $14$ elements each. $14$ is not $2$ times a square.

Comment: The 14 elements are just a section of that row, the entire row is $18 + 14 = 32 = 16 \times 2$ elements. Each section of $14 = 7 \times 2$ elements corresponds to $V_6 \otimes W$, and the $7$ gets added on to $1 + 3 + 5$ to give you your next perfect square.

Comment: Section of which row? There are two rows of length $14$.

Comment: The rows correspond to atomic numbers 1-2 (length=2), 3-10 (length=8), 11-18 (length=8), 19-36 (length=18), 37-54 (length=18), 55-86 (length=32), 87-118 (length=32). The two sections of length 14 that you're talking about are subsections of the two rows of length 32 (look at the atomic numbers and see).

Comment: My understanding (from something I read elsewhere on MO) is that, when the Hamiltonian operator for the hydrogen atom is expressed in the Fourier basis, it is invariant under $SO(4)$ (viewing $\mathbb R^3$ as $S^3$ minus a point by spherical projection) and not just $ SO(3)$. These numbers should be the dimensions of irreps of $SO(3)$ (the spherical harmonics, specifically.

Comment: The $SO(4)$ symmetry is there classically. The extra conserved quantity is the Runge-Lenz vector. @johnbaez has written a bit about this, say, https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gravitational.html

Comment: ... and it's also there quantum mechanically (one has to define the Runge-Lenz operator in a symmetrized fashion).

Comment: Right, and the answer to the question is the existence of an $n^2$ dimensional representation of so(4) as I recall.

Comment: Yeah it should be something like so(4) = so(3)×so(3) (at least, at the level of the algebra and maybe with su(2) instead of so(3)). Then one set of $|l,m\rangle$ spherical harmonics is for the rotational motion as in any radial potential, and there's another one for the radial motion in this case due to the augmented symmetry group? Although this should be something like $|n,q\rangle$, I'm not sure what the $q$ quantum number is about. I'm pretty sure I saw a paper doing this a while back

Comment: Here is a paper that I found doing this based on a quick search. (I remember the one I was looking at a while back was more readable than this one, so could be worth some more searching) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342408862_Quantum_Runge-Lenz_Vector_and_the_Hydrogen_Atom_the_hidden_SO4_symmetry_using_Computer_Algebra

Comment: A good explanation should also explain why the initial “2” appears only once and the subsequent numbers (8, 18, 32, …) each appear twice.

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I posted a [follow-up question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419212/mathematical-explanation-of-orbital-shell-sizes-why-is-it-sufficient-to-conside) (following a suggestion from Carlo Beenakker) covering aspects of this question that I feel were not covered by the answers to the current question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this answer, I'm going to crib from [this](https://math.ucr.edu/home//baez/hydrogen/4d/hydrogen_4d.pdf) presentation by @JohnBaez and the paper [On the Regularization of the Kepler Problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3695). Milnor's [paper](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/on-the-geometry-of-the-kepler-problem) includes a lot of the same information.

First, I'm going to state a few facts without proof. One can compose the stereographic projection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $S^3$ with the symplectomorphism swapping $p$s and $q$s on $T^*(\mathbb{R}^3)$ to get a symplectomorphism from the punctured $T^*(S^3)$ to $T^*(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Furthermore, one can show that the Hamiltonian flow of $p^2$ on a a constant energy surface in $T^*(S^3)$ maps to the Hamiltonian flow of the Kepler potential on $T^*(\mathbb{R}^3)$. This maps the constant energy classical mechanics of a negative energy state in the Kepler potential to a free particle on $S^3$ with fixed energy. This also exhibits the $SO(4)$ symmetry as rotations on $S^3$. Thus (and I'm still undecided if there's some handwaving here), the energy eigenstates in the quantum theory should be irreps of $SO(4)$. You can also exhibit the $SO(4)$ symmetry directly in the quantum theory, so any handwaving isn't a problem.

To see what the representations are, the $SO(4)$ action on $S^3$ can be exhibited by the two $SU(2)$ factors in $\operatorname{Spin}(4)$ acting on both sides of $S^3 \cong SU(2)$. The element $(-I,-I) \in SU(2) \times SU(2)$ acts trivially, so you get an $SO(4)$ action.

With this, we can decompose a la the Peter–Weyl theorem:
$$
L^2(S^3) \cong \bigoplus_i \rho_i \otimes \rho_i^\star
$$
Each $\rho_i$ is an irrep of $SU(2)$, and those irreps can be labelled by an integer $n$. Thus, the problem decomposes into $n^2$-dimensional irreps of $SO(4)$, which explains the question asked.

[N.B. -- I'd be interested in understanding if this can be done "all at once" as opposed to working with constant energy surfaces and arguing by scaling as I see in the references. If I have time, I'd also want to show that the different irreps of SO(4) have different energies, or maybe I'm missing something obvious. This can all be done by looking at the symmetry explicitly in the quantum theory, I'm sure, but it would be nice to see it geometrically.]

Comment: the key problem I see is how to extend this argument for the hydrogen atom (one electron in a 1/r potential), to atoms containing multiple electrons (which will interact with the core as well as with themselves); this extension would then need to explain how the $n$ ordering rule becomes the $n+l$ ordering rule (and thus the sequence 2,8,18,32,... becomes 2,8,8,18,18,...); one of the papers I cite invokes  the chain SO(4,2) $\rightarrow$ SO(3,2) $\rightarrow$ SO(3) $\otimes$ SO(2) to arrive at the $n+l$ rule, no idea if that makes sense or not.

Comment: Sure. This is only intended to give the "more conceptual explanation" for the appearance of $2n^2$ in the Hydrogen atom. Multiple electrons are hard.

Comment: Thanks! I have to think about the $SO(4)$ action in a quiet room for a few minutes, but something like "the $n^2$-dimensional space is an irreducible representation of a larger set of symmetries" is totally the kind of answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 29):

> So, in short, the perfect squares arise as the sums of the first $k$
> odd numbers, and the invariant subspaces arrange themselves into
> energy levels that way because... well, here I get stuck.

To get "unstuck", the following consideration may help:

The key property to consider is the number $N$ of nodes of the electronic wave function. *Wave functions with the same number of nodes have approximately the same energy.* We say that states with the same $N$ form a "shell". (The integer $n=N+1$ is called the [principal quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_quantum_number).)

The number of states ("orbitals") in a shell now follows by counting the number $\sum_{l=0}^{N}(2l+1)=
(N+1)^2$ of eigenfunctions of the angular momentum operator with *at most* $N$ nodes – "at most" because the radial wave function can provide the remaining nodes. Including spin the number of states in a shell is then $2n^2$.

---

So the $2n^2$ rule applies to *shells*, labeled by the principal quantum number $n$. The statement that "states with the same $n$ have the same energy" is only an approximation, which is why the rows of the periodic table do not strictly follow the $2n^2$ rule. For example, the $n=3$ row has only 8 elements, not 18, because the $n=4,l=0$ state has lower energy than the $n=3,l=2$ states.
More accurate considerations, see [Theoretical justification of Madelung's rule](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed056p714), show that the energy is an increasing function of the number
$$W=n+l-\frac{l}{l+1}.$$
The physics here is that the $n$-dependence of the energy accounts for the attraction of electrons to the core, while the $l$-dependence accounts for their mutual repulsion. In atomic hydrogen, which has a single electron, the energy is only dependent on $n$, without any $l$-dependence (at least if we neglect relativistic effects).
If we approximate $W\approx n+l$ (the socalled "$n+l$ rule") we obtain the length $L_n$ of the $n$-th row in the periodic table as
$$L_n=2\sum_{l=0}^{\text{Int}\,[n/2]}(2l+1)=2\left(1+\text{Int}\,[n/2]\right)^2$$
$$\qquad=2, 8, 8, 18, 18, 32,32,\;\;\text{for}\;\;n=1,2\ldots 7.$$
So this explains why the initial "2" appears only once and the subsequent numbers appear twice (Dan Romik's question).

---

**Bottom line:**

**Q:** *"Is there a good mathematical explanation for why orbital lengths in the periodic table are perfect squares doubled?"*

**A:** I don't think so, Madelung's $n+l$ rule requires explicit consideration of the electrostatics of the problem.

However, there have been symmetry based attempts to obtain that rule, as described in 
[Ordinal explanation of the periodic system of chemical elements.](https://www.cs.utep.edu/vladik/1998/tr98-5b.pdf) and in [Some evidence about the dynamical group SO(4,2) symmetries of the periodic table of elements](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/qua.560070705).

Comment: _"Wave functions with the same number of nodes have approximately the same energy."_ is this an observation based on the hydrogen atom and other systems? Or is there some general proof of this? (presumably for systems with a finite number of nodes, are they always bound states?)

Comment: That the energy eigenvalue depends only on the principal quantum number $n$ is exact for the hydrogen atom, so for a single electron in the $1/r$ potential. Even there, it no longer holds if we include spin-orbit interaction. For more than a single electron the energy depends on both $n$ and the angular momentum quantum number $l$ separately.

Comment: I wondered if you were making some statement in general for bound states in QM, or if you were making a statement about the hydrogen atom only. I think it does hold including the spin orbit interaction because this is subleading and the statement is only approximate?

Comment: for a qualitative explanation of the statement that the energy increases with increasing number of nodes, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186140 --- and you're right, spin-orbit coupling does not affect the ordering of the levels, I was referring to the fact that the energy of the hydrogen atom depends on $n$ and $l$ separately once you include spin-orbit coupling.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks that answer gives a good explanation

Comment: Just to be clear, in that physics.stackexchange post, the answer with the many upvotes seems rather suspect to me, whereas the (accepted) answer with currently only one upvote makes sense.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt what do you not like about the upvoted answer?

Comment: @Joe - The fact that in a (self-)interfering wave there are regions of destructive interference does not imply that the wave is somehow impeded from traveling and hence that its position is more constrained. That's not how how waves work, that's not how the definition of the uncertainty $\Delta x$ works, and one can also then not conclude that $\Delta p$ is increased - that's not how the uncertainty principle works.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean exactly by “electronic wave functions”? Are they solutions to [Schrödinger’s equation for a multi-electron atom](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78959/schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-for-multi-electron-atoms)? And if so, I was under the impression that the Hamiltonian eigenfunctions for this system do not have an analytic description for anything heavier than a helium atom, so how is the principal quantum number even defined?

Comment: @DanRomik -- the quantum numbers $n,l,m$ refer to a basis set of single-electron wave functions. The many-electron wave function is expanded in this basis set. There are many techniques to do this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_interaction

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful. Having now read a bit more about the subject, I think from a mathematician’s point of view it’s really important to understand that these many-electron wave functions expanded as Slater determinants are not actually solutions to the Schrodinger’s equation for a multi-electron atom, but only approximations. In fact the whole orbital shell model seems to be only a useful approximation to a much more complex picture. So while your answer provides some good insight about OP’s question, …

Comment: … I feel like there is still a big gap in my understanding of where orbital shells come from, mathematically, or indeed whether the notion of “orbital shell” even makes sense as a well-defined mathematical concept if one takes Schrodinger’s equation as the basic model for a multi-electron atom. I hope you or someone else could address this issue in more detail. Specifically, I’m hoping for an answer that starts from the (many-electron) Schrodinger’s equation and, possibly after several steps of making simplifying assumptions (which are precisely stated), ends up with the series 2, 8, 8, 18, …

Comment: @DanRomik -- that is a great question, why not ask it (as a separate question); this particular question has an accepted answer, so it's done.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker great idea. It might take me a couple of days but I’ll work on it soon.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I posted a follow-up question, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/419212/78525).

Comment: Thanks for linking to your question. I have to learn more physics, to understand what you have written.